# react setstate TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

```
class CheckBox extends React.Component{
  constructor(checked){
    super(checked);
    this.state={checked:false}
  }
  handleChange(event){
    this.setState({checked:!this.state.checked});
  }
  render(){
    var msg;
    if(this.state.checked){
      msg= "checked"
    }else{
      msg="unchecked"
    }
    return(
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <h3>Checkbox is {msg}</h3>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

it said

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

i don't know the reason

Comment: You have to bind your `handleChange()` function. You can do it in the constructor: `this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);`

Answer (score 3):

Either bind `this` to your function in the constructor

```
constructor(checked){
    super(checked);
    this.state={checked:false}

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/gaby/chazb1ju/

---

Or pass an arrow function when binding the handler to the event

```
<input type="checkbox" onChange={(e)=>this.handleChange(e)} />
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/gaby/sjjrrtsu/

Comment: Or just bind `handleChange()` by making it an arrow function.